# Compare String in Database to String in Android Studio

Tags: java, database, sqlite, android-studio

I am trying to compare a String in a Column in my SQLite Database to another String that i created while using cursor and Database Helper.

When i run the app despite what the database has, the app only goes to the UserMenu.class

Part of code: 
(the things commented out is me trying various things out. )

---

```java
public void onClick(View v) {

    String email = Username.getText().toString();

    String pass = Password.getText().toString();


    String role = " ";

    String test2 = "Admin"; 

    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+ DatabaseHelper.COL_3+ " =? AND "+ DatabaseHelper.COL_2+ "=?",new String[]{email, pass});
    if (cursor!=null){
        if (cursor.getCount()> 0){

            db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+ DatabaseHelper.COL_4+ " =?", new String[]{role});
            if(role.equals(test2)) {
                cursor.moveToNext();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+ DatabaseHelper.COL_3+ " =?", new String[]{role2});
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cursor count: "+cursor.getCount(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminMenu.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                cursor.moveToNext();
                //moveToUser();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+ DatabaseHelper.COL_3+ " =?", new String[]{role});
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cursor count: "+cursor.getCount(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserMenu.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid email and/or password. Please try again.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+ DatabaseHelper.COL_4+ " =?", new String[]{role});`

is not much use as the result, the Cursor it returns, is not used.

The line `if(role.equals(test2))` will always be false as role will be " " and test2 will be "Admin". So you always go to userMenu.

I guessing you want similar to

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+ DatabaseHelper.COL_3+ " =? AND "+ DatabaseHelper.COL_2+ "=?",new String[]{email, pass});
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){

    //db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+ DatabaseHelper.COL_4+ " =?", new String[]{role});
    if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_4)).equals(test2)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminMenu.class);
        cursor.close();
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserMenu.class);
        cursor.close();
        startActivity(i);
    }

} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid email and/or password. Please try again.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    cursor.close();
}
```

No good checking if Cursor is null it not be null from query. query fail or get good Cursor. Cursor if no rows Cursor not move.

Using moveToFirst replaces getCount as moveToFirst will be false if count 0 if not it move the Cursor position to first row and values can be got from the Cursor. So does two things.

Not know if row found has proper value for role but other query with comments now will get all row with role not just from email row so any ADMIN and always AdminMenu. So first query only needed I think.

Comment: if (cursor.getString(DatabaseHelper.COL_4).equals(test2)) {                                                   This part of the code gets an error that says " getString(int) in Cursor cannot be applied to (boolean) "                                                Any way to fix that?

Comment: @MarcosC my wrong code, sorry. Have edited answer I forget include `cursor.getColumnByIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_4)`, this get column index from column name. `cursor.getString(?)` needs ? be column index (int) not column name (string). Did not run test code just simple syntax check was done.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined:

```
String role = " ";
String test2 = "Admin";
```

and these variables are not changed anywhere in your code.
So the condition:

```
role.equals(test2)
```

returns `false` and the `else` block is executed.